# insert value from one table to another checking id

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables.All the ids are include in table one (`Tbl_Distributor`). 2nd table have all the names.

I want to add all the names to first table according to id.

My select query as below.

[image]

```
 INSERT INTO dbo.Tbl_Distributor(Giv_Name) where dealercode= a.dealercode

 SELECT a.dealercode,d.nameinfull  
 FROM dealerplacement a,dealer d
 where a.dealercode= d.dealercode
 order by a.dealercode ASC
```

This returns `nameinfull` and `dealercode`. I want to add this `nameinfull` to `Tbl_Distributor` .

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: We don't have enough info. Please provide 2-3 example rows from each table, and a desired result example, too.

Comment: I update my question.please check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE R
SET Giv_Name = D.FirstName
FROM
   dbo.Tbl_Distributor R
   INNER JOIN dbo.Dealer D
      ON R.Dis_ID = D.DealerCode
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use INSERT here. You need to use update. I'd do such a task using cursors.

```
declare @id int, @name varchar(1000)
DECLARE c CURSOR FOR
SELECT a.dealercode,d.nameinfull  
 FROM dealerplacement a,dealer d
 where a.dealercode= d.dealercode
 order by a.dealercode ASC

OPEN c

FETCH NEXT FROM c 
INTO @id, @name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

update Tbl_Distributor set Giv_Name = @name where dealercode = @id

FETCH NEXT FROM c 
INTO @id, @name
end

CLOSE c;
DEALLOCATE c;
```

Also, I'd use join in the select statement:

```
SELECT a.dealercode,d.nameinfull  
FROM dealerplacement a inner join dealer d
on a.dealercode= d.dealercode
order by a.dealercode ASC
```

Comment: Cursors are the *last* thing to advise here. An awful solution.